# How to use systemd hybrid-sleep instead of suspend under GNOME in Linux?

Tags: linux, gnome, systemd, hibernate, sleep

How can I make GNOME 3 use systemd hybrid-sleep instead of suspend, when closing the lid or using suspend from the menu?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/q/719447/151431) on multiple stack exchange sites. You have already received an answer on [su].

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/719488/162573